# How to scale a graphic to the exact size I want to print out?

Tags: digital-printing

I have made some sidewalk textures which is 76mm x 297mm in Photoshop but when I printed them out in A4 size 4 of each edges got about 5mm blanket spaces.(see pic below)

That means my whole A4 picture in Photoshop is scaled to about 95% when printed out and the shop owner told me that were the printer's limitation.

My question is

1. Is different printer have different blanket spaces? In my case its about 5mm each side.
2. If so can i just scale the texture to 105% in PS to make it the exact same size I want when printed out?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Most inkjet printers have an unprintable border area around the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all printers have blank edges so that they can handle the paper without ruining the internals of the printer. Simply there has to be something to hold onto. The way you get rid of this is to print on a oversized paper and cut the image out*. To do this properly you need an image that is slightly larger than your intended size (called overprint), so that your cutting errors are not visible.

The image should not get scaled by this process though (be careful some applications notably acrobat has a option to scale to fit, do not enable this), just part of it omitted.

* no amount of scaling helps since the printer will reject those pixels. So no way around this without changing the printer to some model that can do this, or cutting teh image.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advises. Printing on a oversized paper seems a way to go but since the size of the paper we use to print is usually goes double like A3 equals to 2x A4 so I think the cost of printing an A4 image on A3 would be expensive.

Ah I thing I have to clarify is if I scale the picture to 105% and crop it to A4 size in Photoshop, then it will turn out like what I want?
Thanks

Comment: I just got another ideas since the A4 is 210*297 and the blank edge is 5mm each side, how about if I create an picture in Photoshop which the size is 195*282(5mm tolerance in case the printer have more than 5mm blank edge) and select an A4 to print, will my picture printed 100% the size I want and without any scale by the printer itself?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you should have the possibility in Photoshop to actually print the media to the dimensions you have set. (100 % with no scaling) - check down the bottom the settings. Hope that helps. [image: screen capture]

Comment: Though the downside is that you will still get a blank margin for the part along the edge. However, perhaps a little more control over the output.

Comment: Else, previous versions of Adobe Illustrator would allow you to define the printing zone of a document according to your printer (there was a dotted line indicating the limit of what got printed) - these days, you preview it and can actually drag it around in the Print dialog box. Perhaps an alternative to have a little more control.

Comment: Thanks for the info but the shop Im going to print pictures use stock windows interface to print files. Also even if I can set to print 100% some part of my picture will still be trimmed.